Stripe Express Checkout buttons clipped
Stripe Express Checkout buttons are being clipped - apparently they are afforded insufficient height by the iframe(?).
Considered approaches:

I can use setTimeout to set the height after load ('ready' listener). But the wait after 'ready' varies, and - more substantially - this doesn't seem to work for mobile.
I have also tried using the class names the buttons are embedded with (as solutions to similar problems suggest) but I haven't got this to work. I'm unsure whether that's me, or that solution doesn't hold for the express checkout element.
I have also seen suggestion of 'custom' integrations - which I think suggests hiding the buttons, and creating proxies. I am considering this a last resort at the moment.

Is anyone familiar with this problem - better yet a solution?
Express checkout js reference: https://docs.stripe.com/js/elements_object/create_express_checkout_element

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm not sure what you mean by "buttons are being clipped". If you want all buttons to be shown and hide the overflow menu, you should set overflow to "never"

Hey @qichuan. I mean that they are only partially visible: when the buttons load, the iframe is apparently automatically given a height, and in my case that height is insufficient and the overflow gets hidden so I see only about half of a payment option button. I wonder if it relates to the dimensions of the parent containing the express checkout element at the time of mount - I will test this and report back. I am aware of the overflow option, thanks.

Developer error: I'd forgotten that I'd set zoom on big displays. [emoji] facepalm [emoji]
Setting a balancing zoom on the express checkout element resolved the matter. [emoji] facepalm [emoji][emoji] facepalm [emoji]
